# Plugin translation ready - mo file not loaded

Tags: localization

I try to localize my plugin.

in the plugin php file my-plugin.php I have the textdomain

```
Text Domain: my-plugin
```

and the action on "plugins_loaded"

```
// load textdomain on plugin
function my-plugin_load_textdomain() {
  echo '<script>console.log("fired");</script>'; 
  if (load_plugin_textdomain( 'my-plugin', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' )) {
       echo '<script>console.log("ok");</script>';
  } else {
       echo '<script>console.log("not");</script>';
  }
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'my-plugin_load_textdomain' );
```

The plugin itselfs displays a shortcode and loads the my-plugin-output.php which has following echos

```
<h4><?php _e( 'Ausgabe', 'my-plugin' ); ?></h4>
```

I have in the folder languages the my-plugin-de.mo files which I translated via poedit to my-plugin-en.mo. The translation is complete. Following files are in the languages folder:

> my-plugin-de.mo
>
> my-plugin-de.pot
>
> my-plugin-en.mo
>
> my-plugin-en.po

I have read several tutorials, however many of them say I should add a define WP-LANG, but this is not needed in WordPress 4.0 and above?

My site language is now selected as english. The basic code in the plugin is german, but it should display the english language.

When I activate the plugin the console gives me the message that the load_plugin_textdomain returns false, on codex I see this

> Returns false, if the language file could not be loaded (it is not
>   readable or the mo file reader can not understand it).

What does this mean? I translated the files with poedit, and I can open it in poedit without problems. If I validate the en.po file in poedit, it says everything is ok. The language folder is also correct.

Am I missing here something? Thanks very much

EDIT:

The output from debug translations:

```
Debug Translations (Version 2013.09.05)

Locale: en_US


Domain:    default
File:      C:\xampp\htdocs\projekte\WP/wp-content/languages/en_US.mo (not found)
Called in: C:\xampp\htdocs\projekte\WP\wp-settings.php line 306 load_default_textdomain

Domain:    twentyfourteen
File:      C:\xampp\htdocs\projekte\WP/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/languages/en_US.mo (not found)
Called in: C:\xampp\htdocs\projekte\WP\wp-content\themes\twentyfourteen\functions.php line 68 load_theme_textdomain

Domain:    twentyfourteen
File:      C:\xampp\htdocs\projekte\WP/wp-content/languages/themes/twentyfourteen-en_US.mo (not found)
Called in: C:\xampp\htdocs\projekte\WP\wp-content\themes\twentyfourteen\functions.php line 68 load_theme_textdomain
```

My plugin is not listed at all? It is activated and does also output on the page? This is strange

Comment: Try [Debug Translations](https://marketpress.com/product/debug-translations/).

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question with the output from the debug translations. I do not understand why the the plugin translation is not listed

Comment: Hmm, `function my-plugin_load_textdomain()` is not a vlid function name. `-` is not allowed here.

Comment: Thanks, no sorry it is my_plugin_load_textdomain, this was just a dummy name

Answer (score 2):

The `load_plugin_textdomain()` function had not the same textdomain as given in the PHP file of the plugin. I had written dummy names for this thread, therefore it could not be seen.

But I changed it. Also the `.mo` and `.po` files have to have the localization code as set in the WordPress database at `WP_LANG`. Strangely, there was no localization code in the database, the field was empty. I added it and named the files new, and now it is working!

This article helped a lot: https://localise.biz/help/wordpress/loading-translations